# Syntax for loading vs. installing libraries.

Tags: r, syntax

I've been an active `R` user for several years now, and something has always confused me. When installing packages (e.g. `dplyr`), one must specify the name of the package as a string i.e.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

Rather than

```
install.packages(dplyr)
```

This makes sense to me, since `"dplyr"` would pass as the name of the package and not as an object, which would be implied by `dplyr` without the quotation marks.

However, when we go to load the library, both the string and object version pass through and load the package. Both of the following correctly load the package:

```
library("dplyr")
detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
```

There is no object named `dplyr` in my workspace, and I don't understand why these two `base` functions would have different syntax. I also don't understand why the version without the quotation marks *wouldn't* evaluate the object. For example

```
dplyr <- "mada"
install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
```

The above **installs** `mada`, but **loads** `dplyr`, even though `dplyr` is an object that evaluates to `"mada"`. Note that I am working in `RStudio`v.0.99.467 on Mac OS 10.10.4, if that matters. 
Is there a reason for this, or is it simply that the functions work differently?

Comment: It's basically an accident of history.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`library` function takes package `name` as first argument. This `name` actually refers to the name passed as package argument rather than any value associated to that name. `library` function internally converts the package argument to a character literal (except when `character.only` is set to `TRUE`).

So,

```
plyr <- "dplyr"
library(plyr)
```

will undergo

```
if(!character.only)
    package <- as.character(substitute(plyr))
```

to become

```
package <- "plyr"
```

`install.packages` takes a character vector as name(s) of packages to be installed.

```
dd <- "plyr"
install.packages(dd)
```

This would install `plyr`.

It is because`install.packages` don't do any such conversion with `pkgs` argument. So `install.packages` installs what `pkgs` refers to.

Answer (score 8):

> I don't understand why these two base functions would have different syntax.

It’s hard to speculate about the reasons for specific language design decisions. The decision to allow unquoted names for the `library` call has been criticised by many prominent R programmers as illogical, inconsistent and unnecessary, but here we are.

Besides the argument that it’s (marginally) more convenient not to type the quotes, another potential reason is similarity to other languages: for instance, in Python you `import` libraries by specifying their name like so: `import lib_name`, *not* `import 'lib_name'`. This encourages library writers to choose library names that are valid identifiers in the language (in Python, loaded libraries are objects that you need to refer to). This is less relevant in R, where you rarely refer to the library besides loading it.

> I also don't understand why the version without the quotation marks *wouldn't* evaluate the object.

Because R allows [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). In particular, function arguments are only evaluated when they are referred to, not before:

```
f = function (arg) {}
f(stop('this won’t raise an error!'))
```

`arg` is never used, so never evaluated.

In the case of `library`, the argument isn’t evaluated either. Instead, it’s used in unevaluated form via [`substitute(package)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you look through the source code for `?library` you will see at [line 230 click here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/base/R/library.R#L230) :

```
if (!character.only) 
            package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

The package name that the user supplies is coerced to character then concatenated:

```
pkgname <- paste("package", package, sep = ":")
```

This is what allows the input without quotes for library. `install.packages` does not have the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the right answer. I accepted the answer by Narendra because it seems like they are a new user in need of rep and also had the correct response with a good explanation. I hope this is okay with you, and thanks for your help (again).

Comment: @ChrisC I disagree. You should accept the best answer and not accept another answer because you feel sorry for the other user. For the community it is the best that the best answer is accepted.

Comment: @Jaap Thanks for the input. In that case, I thought that both answers were equally correct, though Narendra's was more understandable and complete, and thus I would accept the answer the same way.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to load `mada` instead of `dplyr` in your example, try using the option `character.only = TRUE`

```
dplyr <- "mada"
install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr, character.only=TRUE)
```

See the documentation `?library` for more information.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this is very useful. However, I was asking more for an explanation of why this occurs rather than a workaround. Can you comment on why the default would be `character.only = F`? I'll keep the question open for a little bit longer.